Clip map image layer with arc gis pro
I have a satellite raster image layer file here, and vector data for the parcels of Philadelphia in a layer file here. I can load each into ArcGIS Pro and see the parcels on top of the satellite image (much like you can see here if you turn on aerial imagery).
For each parcel, I want to cut its portion of the raster image, and save it to disk (or cloud...there are 600k parcels...). Thus, for each parcel, I want an image file with the aerial view directly over head (and nothing else).
I thought I could do this with the clip geoprocessing tool in arcgis pro, but when I put the raster image into the input layer, I get the following error:
Error 000840  The value is not a Feature Layer.
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Scene Layer.
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Building Scene Layer.
ERROR 000840: The value is not a File. 


Likewise when I try to put the vector data into the clip features:
Error 000840  The value is not a Feature Layer.


Parcel data from here
Imagery data from here

Try using Clip Raster (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/clip.htm) instead of Clip.
